# On what Standard version the Magento Enterprise version 1.8.0 is based?

Tags: php, versioning, magento

I need a suggestion on what Standard Magento version the Enterprise version 1.8.0 could be based?

Possible answers are:

```
1.4.0
1.4.0.1
1.4.1.0
1.4.1.1
```

We have one customer with a error related probably to one of the versions which can be found on forum. But to proof that it's related to certain error I need to know to what version 1.8.0 Enterprise version is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento Community (CE) and Enterprise (EE) are separately maintained codebases with different code repositories and everything. So, even though some code is promoted from (tested on, more accurately) CE, they are not "based" on each other.

This is an ongoing issue as some improvements (such as non-EAV caching tables and PCI compliance related code in EE) are drawing the two codebases apart.

With more information on the error, some here may be able to help solve the problem.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/enterprise-community-faqs
"Magento Enterprise Edition shares the same base as Magento Community Edition"